# Interval Tree algorithm inplementation

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

I recently went through the implementation of Interval tree on http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interval-tree/, Here the algorithm suggests to use a max value at each subtree.

And the algo for finding overlap is as:

> Interval overlappingIntervalSearch(root, x)
>
> 1. If x overlaps with root's interval, return the root's interval.
> 2. If left child of root is not empty and the max  in left child is greater than x's low value, recur for left child
> 3. Else recur for right child.

What I don't understand is why use a max value, it can be done by comparing the intervals also to get a LOG(N) result.

```java
public class IntervalTree {
    private Node ROOT;

    private class Node {

        Point data;
        Node left, right;

        public Node(Point data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        new IntervalTree().task();
    }

    private void task() {
        insert();
        Node pop = findInterval(ROOT, new Node(new Point(6,7)));
        if (pop != null) System.out.println(pop.data.toString());
        else System.out.println("No overlap");
    }

    private Node findInterval(Node root, Node node) {
        if (root == null) return null;
        if (overlap(root.data, node.data)) return root;
        else if (node.data.x < root.data.x) return findInterval(root.left, node);
        return findInterval(root.right, node);
    }

    private boolean overlap(Point one, Point two) {
        return two.x <= one.y && one.x <= two.y;
    }

    private void insert() {
        int data[][] = new int[][]{{15, 20}, {10, 30}, {17, 19}, {5, 20}, {12, 15}, {30, 40}};
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            ROOT = insert(data[i]);
    }

    private Node insert(int[] pt) {
        return insert(ROOT, new Node(new Point(pt[0], pt[1])));
    }

    private Node insert(Node root, Node node) {
        if (root == null) return node;
        else if (node.data.x < root.data.x)
            root.left = insert(root.left, node);
        else root.right = insert(root.right, node);
        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: can't comment on incomplete code, how are nodes added and removed.

Comment: I have updated the code, insertion is there, and I haven't yet implemented deletion.

Comment: Is that java code? Then you **must** add a `java` tag... In any case, did you look at that picture? You can see that the maximum value *need not* be contained in the interval. For example the root has interval `[15, 20]` but maximum value `40`, so you cannot recover that information from the root interval alone.

Comment: I meant that as we  just need to output the overlapping interval, then why do we need the max value.

Comment: That would be useful, if we want the most overlapping interval, that is the one with least difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

max is needed to find the overlap, eg use this data

```
 {{15, 20}, {10, 11}, {17, 22}, {5, 20}, {12, 25}, {30, 40}};
```

and search for `24`